Child container is ignoring parent container box and margins on RHS Margins
Context: Trying to build a responsive 'Menu' for an online course I'm taking.
Problem: Cannot understand why the child containers are ignoring the constraints of the parent container on the RHS of the browser window.
Describing the solution in images: As I'm not sure where my problem lies across my index.html or style.css file, I wanted to try and describe the problem in attached images. As a newbie, I'm hoping these images will make the problem and solution obvious to more seasoned developers. See attached.
Window at ~75% (Medium Media Type), where the larger 3rd box is having the issue/problem
Window at ~40% (Small Media Type), where the all 3 boxes are having the issue/problem

Thanks for the guidance @Paulie_D I'll improve my question structures going forward, and will aim to provide solutions for future users, and not only my own problems. Cheers and all the best.

Hi @Paulie_D please see my answer. I solved the problem myself with the help of GenAI

The GenAI solved my problem, and importantly, was really friendly and welcoming too.

The solution I found was indeed something simple :-D
Could fix the problem by adding padding:
.parent-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 40px;
  }

Not sure if this is the perfect solution for all others, but is workable for some contexts.
